# How to res.send() array with forEach()

Tags: node.js, express, response

Trying to get every item of an array sent to the client.
But, for some reason it does not print into the browser

It works for console log, but not for res.send()

Is this possible without a template engine?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let theArray = [
  {id: '123441234',
  name: 'Joe',
  age: 21
},
{id: '458834',
name: 'Steve',
age: 28
}
]

app.get("/", (req,res) => {

  res.send(
    theArray.forEach(product => {
      `<h1>${product.name}</h1><br>
      <h5>${product.age}</h5>
      `
    });
  )
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array instead of using a `forEach` loop. That way you can [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the values and send the `html` string:

```
app.get("/", (req,res) => {

  res.send(
    theArray.map(product =>
      `<h1>${product.name}</h1><br>
      <h5>${product.age}</h5>
      `
    ).join('');
  )
})
```

This would result in your request getting the html:

```
<h1>Joe</h1><br>
<h5>21</h5>
<h1>Steve</h1><br>
<h5>28</h5>
```

Answer (score 1):

`res.send` param must be a string and here it is an undefined object (`forEach`).

This should work :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let theArray = [
  {id: '123441234',
  name: 'Joe',
  age: 21
},
{id: '458834',
name: 'Steve',
age: 28
}
]

app.get("/", (req,res) => {

  res.send(
    theArray.map(product => {
      `<h1>${product.name}</h1><br>
      <h5>${product.age}</h5>
      `
    }).join(' ');
  )
})

app.listen(3000)
```